# How can I read left and right mouse clicks within a node script, no DOM/window

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am making a basic game with node that will run in the terminal.

Hopefully there is a library or an easy way to read left and right mouse clicks, I want my left click to trigger one function I've written and the right click to trigger another function.

I've done some basic googling and checked NPM but they all seem to require clicks within the context of the browser.

Is this possible within MacOS for a terminal app?

Comment: so, a text based game, with mouse clicks? sounds wrong

Comment: short answer - no, you can't detect mouse clicks simply in a CLI program

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually got it working, using the library terminal-kit

Comment: I stand corrected then :p